# Cufon menu not appearing on IE7

Tags: menu, cufon

Hi I am using Cufon on my Wordpress site and everything is fine except a menu on IE6 and IE7.
On every other browser it looks fine. The code I am using for menu is:

```
<div id="meni">
      <ul>
        <li class="home" title="Return to Homepage"><a href="home">HOME</a></li
```

etc..

Cufon code in the head is:

Cufon.replace('#meni', {hover: true} ); 
Cufon.replace('#meni ul li a', {hover: true} ); 
Cufon.replace('.home a', {hover: true} );

As you can see I have tried different selectors but it still does not work.

Any help please...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. As long as Cufon's selectors are (less or more) js framework dependent IE7 is having issues matching certain elements. In my case CUFON was loaded before jQuery. Had to reorder to make sure jQuery is present when CUFON fw is loaded.

Comment: +1 for you. Such a perfect answer to the issue that I had. The cufon text did not show up properly in IE7. As per your answer, I really did notice that I was loading jQuery after the cufon lib was loaded. So all I did was switched the places of jquery with the cufon library thereby making jQuery load first. And voila! IE7 respected it & showed the cufon text perfectly. Thank you once again!